# Suddenly receiving Quota exceeded errors with Youtube API when try to upload videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, quota

We have used the Youtube API for years and have just started having this new issue. We upload real estate property videos for agents. Maybe 10-20 a day on average. A couple weeks back we on boarded a new client that had about 500 properties and we received the quota exceeded error message which I thought might be just an issue for a day or two but it's now something that happens every single day and we are back to our normal 10-20 a day average. The quota is still showing as 10,000 requests per day so not sure what might have happened but it seems that ever since that spike that there's some correlation. We shouldn't need an increase in quota so didn't go that route. Any thoughts or advice appreciated. But here's the actual error message which seems to reference a "getting-started" quota.

> The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question, not a programming question

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes it is...  Please refer to this link.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Comment: Any company can say that questions belong on Stack Overflow, but… the question still needs to meet the guidelines here and be on-topic. Quota questions don’t fit here. The page you linked to may not be clear about it but … it’s for programming-specific API questions, not service quotas, billing issues, etc.

Comment: See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: It's not a quota question. I understand quotas and that they exist. The question is does anyone know of how or why we might suddenly start getting a quota exceeded error message after years of using the same app on Youtube. It's seems quite unusual and I thought perhaps someone else has experienced/solved this.